# Logic app blob trigger not fired on subfolder

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I am referring to this feedback:

[Azure Storage Blob Trigger to fire when files added in Sub Folders](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/20164843-azure-storage-blob-trigger-to-fire-when-files-adde)

I have a Azure Logic App that is fired every time  a blob is added in a container. This works fine when all the documents are at the root of the container.

[image: Azure Logic App - Blob Trigger]

Inside my container, I have a dynamic number of (virtual) sub-folders. 
When I add a new document in a subfolder (path = `mysubfolder/mynewdocument.txt`), the logic app is not triggered.

This does not really make sense for me as sub-folders in the blob container are virtual. Does anyone find a workaround except putting all the files at the root level ?

I've opened an issue on Github:

https://github.com/Azure/logicapps/issues/20

Comment: I just tested this on netcoreapp2.1 with a standard BlobTrigger and found that it detected my files in subfolders.

Comment: This was a question about logic app not functions or webjobs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior.  None of the Logic App Triggers that work with 'files' support subfolders.

This has been the case with BizTalk Server as well since 2000 so I would not expect a change anytime soon :(.

Please create or vote on a User Voice for this issue: [User Voice - Logic Apps](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps)

Answer (score 2):

> This does not really make sense for me as sub-folders in the blob container are virtual. Does anyone find a workaround except putting all the files at the root level ?

I also can reproduce it on my side. I recommend that you could use the Azure function app blob trigger to instead of Azure Logic App blob trigger. Azure blob trigger function could be fired when you add a new document in a subfolder(virtual).

Comment: Yeah this is what I ended up to do

Answer (score 1):

At the time I was developing this feature (early 2018), [EventGrid](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/event-grid/) was still in preview so I've ended up using [Azure Function - Blob trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-blob-triggered-function).

I would definitely use [EventGrid - Blob Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview) now and it works for Logic App / Function App or with any Http endpoint.